Attic insulation compacted. What is a simple solution?
Previous owner of the house had cameras installed. The electrician had to compact the insulation which I understand is bad. It is the white spray kind.
It was suggested that I could go to the store and unroll some as an easy solution. What type of insulation should I be looking for? What kind of R value should I need, or can I just lay down 17 layers of the cheap stuff?
Many thanks.

Is the compaction in a few small spots or over a few square feet?

We need more details about the issue you are concerned about.   Compacting insulation  degrades its properties to resist the travel of heat and cold. However it does not create a hazard or cause a serious problem.  What needs to be done depends on whether your issue is over a large area or a few spots.

What do you mean by 17 layers?

White spray kind? Do you mean blown fiberglass or foam?

Sounds like you have blown in insulation.  If that's the case, you can buy a bag of the stuff at a big box store and fill in by hand the compacted/low spots.  Be sure to wear a mask.
If the "damage" is more extensive, I would use unfaced fiberglass, 3-1/2" or 6" thick, in either rolls or batts and just lay it down across the disturbed areas.  If you do this, make sure the batts or rolls are butted up tight against each other so as to reduce air leaks.  These can extend across undisturbed areas of insulation as well, so they don't have to be cut to fit exactly the disturbed area.

Note that there's no issue overlaying fiberglass with cellulose if that's what's available.
